# How to Make MoveToTrash mean Delete Permanently by One-liner?

Tags: ubuntu, deleted-files

I did `Move to Trash` > `Empty Trash`. However, .fileNames and .directoryNames stay in the filesystem

- those .files/.directories which have exactly the same name as my deleted files/directories

For instance, select to host the folder where you did removals. All your removals will be shared too. This is not what I want because it can lead to severe mistakes.

I would like to do the thing as a one-liner, probably by `gsettings`. This would help the maintenance and future installations. 
Malyy's answer is about the GUI approach by enabling `Include a delete command bypasses Trash`, but I really need a one-liner.

Systems: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Some of the `.fileNames` and `.directoryNames` are recreated by other programs. Which files specifically we're talking about here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CLI, as requested:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences enable-delete true
```

Explanation requested from OP:

Nautilus is a part of GNOME, so it stores preferences under `org.gnome.nautilus.preferences`. From there, just had to look at the list.

Also, you can get all Nautilus-related settings by `gsettings list-recursively | grep nautilus`.

Comment: in case somebody wants to do this on Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic):
  
`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-delete-permanently true`

Answer (score 2):

In Nautilus -> Preferences -> Properties (or preferences) -> Behaviour

Enable "`Include a delete command bypasses Trash`"

Comment: rm -f .filename