# How to Solve this Read-only file system error?

Tags: filesystems, find

I do

```
find /media/masi/FAT32/ -type f -name '._*' -delete
```

but I get

```
find: cannot delete '/media/masi/FAT32/._booklet.pdf': Read-only file system
```

I do not know how to work with such situations when working in ext4 but searching fat32. There are no permissions/owners in fat32. So I would like to change that all read-write all files in the memory card. However, not sure if it can be done here. It can also be a file system consistency problem but not sure. I just noticed many .dotFiles in the system, which seems to be backup files because I did not use the option described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288639/16920) before. 
I do `ls -la /media/masi/`

```
drwxr-xr-x 29 masi masi 32768 1 1970 FAT32
```

I do `mount -o remount, rw /media/masi/FAT32/` but I get

```
mount: mount point /media/masi/FAT32/ does not occur
```

Command `dmesg | grep FAT32` gives blank. Command `lsblk` also does not show the memory. 
Profiling the memory in Nautilus of Debian 8.25 where I see the main node correctly but subnodes not; in terminal, I can however search the tree but not sure how good it is

> Sorry, could not display all the contents of “handouts.noindex”: Error
>   when getting information for file
>   '/media/masi/FAT32/handouts.noindex/╖Yp╟@≥3.ç╜╩': Input/output error

Memory: Transcend JetDrive Lite 130 128 GB (for Macbook Air 2013-mid)
Hardware: Macbook Air 2013-mid and Dell PC i3 2013
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 8.5

Comment: Is the whole fat32 filesystem readonly or only dot files? If the whole fat32 filesystem is readonly, then it could've been mounted readonly and you can try mount -o remount,rw /media/masi/FAT32

Comment: @Masi I don't see that you say other file in filesystem are read-write (file permission are not useful).  Also I have difficulties to understand your question, because in text it seems that you are asking an other question.  So I think you should start checking `mount` options.

Comment: @Masi you can't tell if filesystem is RW by looking at ls, type `mount | grep FAT32` and paste the output. Actually your filesystem is mounted read-only, I somehow missed the `Read-only file system` in your error. Just run `mount -o remount,rw /media/masi/FAT32`

Comment: try to remount as read-write the filesystem....`mount -o remount, rw /media/masi/FAT32/` . As the error mentioned, the filesystem is read-only

Comment: The access to a VFAT partition often gets implicitly set to RO when there are access/read errors. Try `fsck`ing your drive, and format it if that doesn't help.

Comment: @Murphy What is RO? Read and ... What do you think about this? `fsck.fat32 -cDfty -C 0 /dev/sdxx`. I am not sure if it works; I changed it from ext4. It should run *Run a fat32 file system check and badblocks scan with progress info*.

Comment: RO stands for read-only, in contrast to RW (read-write) access. Better try `fsck.vfat /dev/...` to see if any problems exist at all, then add the `-a` option to repair them. And **before** try to save valuable data from the drive, as you might loose the content in the process.

Comment: follow this https://smallbusiness.chron.com/give-permissions-ubuntu-33174.html
sure problem solve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The access to a VFAT partition often gets implicitly set to read-only when there are access/read errors. In order to check and solve these try the following steps. **Be aware to use the right device, else you can damage your system!**

1. Try to save valuable data from the drive by copying it to some other drive or your home directory.
2. Unmount the drive.
3. Check for problems with `sudo fsck.vfat /dev/...`
4. If `fsck` reports errors, try to repair them: `sudo fsck.vfat -a /dev/...`.
   For more thorough checks see also the `-t` and `-V` options, as well as `-f` to try saving the content of damaged files.
5. After `fsck` has finished you can remove and reconnect the drive and try again to access it.
6. If that doesn't help, try to format the drive: `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/...`.
7. If that still doesn't help, or the problem reoccurs, the drive may be damaged badly and should be discarded.

Comment: I am testing your proposal here http://askubuntu.com/q/789821/25388 Getting some warning about dirty bit.